# How do I query across many tables in redshift without UNION ALL?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm looking for a dumb way to write the same select query across all tables. For example in Google Bigquery I can query like this using wild cards

```
select COMPLICATED QUERY HERE from `myproject:mytable_2017_1_*`;
```

How can I do the equivalent in redshift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wildcard syntax is not available for Amazon Redshift. Each query must specifically reference the table(s) it wishes to use.

You could create a `VIEW` that does the `UNION ALL` for you, and then you could just query the view.

Comment: That sucks, oh well